# Is there a formula $A(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ with k variables that's true for a truth assignment o exactly when a prime number of variables are true under o

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Answer Options:

1. Yes, such a formula exists in principle, but currently, no one knows how to construct it
2. Yes, one can construct such a formula, though it would get quite unwieldy when k is large
3. No, there are far too many primes for this to exist

I have no idea what the answer is. I thought that primality was a concept that is too complicated for propositional logic.

Please help.

Comment: Given any specific $k$, there can only be a finite number of primes smaller or equal to $k$.

Comment: So is the answer no3?

Comment: eh .. no. There are a finite number of primes smaller or equal to $k$, and you should be able to create a formula that states that exactly 2, or 3, or 5 ... or ... variables are true. So, the answer is Yes .. but the question I want you to think about is: given *any* $k$, can you tell me all primes smaller or equal to $k$?

Comment: Yes if k is small enough

Comment: What do you mean by 'small enough'? What would be 'too big'? Are you thinking: "well, at this point the largest known prime is some number, so we can;t go beyond that"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT

Yes, primality in general is not something you want to use propositional logic for, but given any specific $k$, there can only be a finite number of primes smaller or equal to $k$.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  If $k=3$ say, we can obviously create a formula in $3$ variables which is true if and only if two or three variables are true.  Why does it matter that there are primes greater than $3$?  I would pick choice $2$.  What am I missing?

Comment: @saulspatz And that would be my answer as well :)

Comment: Oh, okay.  You didn't dispute the OP's interpretation of your comment, and I took "silence to signify assent."  My mistake.

Comment: @saulspatz No, I *just* went back to the site ... and saw the OP's comment ... guess it wasn't a very good hint ....